# results.empty? in Tiny_Tds

Tags: sql-server, ruby, tiny-tds

```
result = client.execute("SELECT TOP (2000) node_id FROM  [td].[node] WHERE  (node_id = 220)")

puts result

if result.empty?
  puts 'Node id could not found'
else
  puts 'Node is found on the database'
end
```

I'm getting an error when I run this test:

```
undefined method `empty?' for #TinyTds::Result:0x0000002a06d90 (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: What class is `result`?  Does it respond to an `empty?` method?  And--FWIW--you'll get `undefined method 'empty?` error if the value of `result` is `nil`.

Comment: `result =  client.execute("SELECT TOP (2000) node_id FROM  [td].[node] WHERE  (node_id = 220)")`

Comment: user3174886: that assignment snippet is already included in your original question.  You need to determine the class of `result` and see if it responds to `empty?`, keeping in mind that `nil.empty?` will throw an exception.  Or just read the answer below, which does your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I found a way to check as `(result.count == 0)` if its empty.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [TinyTds::Result Class](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds/blob/master/lib/tiny_tds/result.rb) there's no `empty?` method. There's no `empty?` method in Enumerable as well. You should either convert into an array and use empty `to_a.empty?` or check if there's an way in `TinyTds` to return array instead of `TinyTds::Result`.